# C# application works fine on server but throws null exception error on client machine

Tags: c#

Here's the code for line 186.Line 297 on the error refers to THROW on the below code. On the server, there is no error on the above lines. The problem comes when I tried to run the app from client machines. How can it work on Server and failed on client machine with a null exception error? Any idea on this? Thank you.

```
public void saveVote()
{
string val = "";
val = "'" + m_sessid + "','" +
m_nomineeshid + "','" +
m_votershid + "','" +
m_nomineeid + "','" +
m_nominee + "','" +
m_nomineeamh + "','" +
m_voteregcode + "','" +
m_votershno + "','" +
m_votershamt + "','" +
m_crtby + "','" +
m_crtdt + "','" +
m_isnombynoninf + "','" +
m_nomineeregcode + "','" +
m_isvoterinf + "','" +
m_isnomforbod + "','" +
m_votercode + "'";
try
{
dac.Insert("tblVotForBoDNominees", val);
}
catch (Exception q)
{
throw new Exception(q.Message + " " + 
q.InnerException.Message.ToString());
}
}
Line 297 on the error refres to THROW on the above code
```

Comment: How about sharing some code? I mean, my guess is that if it is a null reference and on the server you receive information, maybe the client doesn't have access to the data which is being used?

Comment: the code is a bit long and this forum is not allowing me to post long comments

Comment: Any means of sharing please suggest

Answer (score 1):

At this line in Vote.cs file might be a call of external resource like environment variable. In such case it's possible, as it requires to set it up on every machine.
Provide the code, please. There can be different reasons and it's difficult to  guess blinded.

Comment: Here is the code

Comment: the code is a bit long and this forum is not allowing me to post long comments

Comment: Any suggestion on how to share my code please?

Comment: Nova, you can edit the post and put it there. Or at least some lines mentioned in error trace.

Comment: Please see the piece of code on my post

Comment: I think, you don't have DB set up.

Answer (score 0):

check the lines number from log error in "Vote.cs" file, you are using something that only exists in your server but not in clients.